# Unable to boot Ubuntu on Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition

Tags: 20.04, dell, xps

I have an XPS 13 9300. It is a "developer edition" which means it shipped from the factory with Ubuntu installed. About a year ago, one day I powered up and it would not boot. The warranty and my "pro support" expired a couple of months ago. I suspect that the hard drive failed. How can I test if the hard drive is the cause of my inability to boot? I can get into the BIOS. The text I see on screen when I boot is:

[    1.829170] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to query device: -5

Does that indicate what the problem may be? Any recommendations on how I should proceed to make this laptop usable again? If the data is not recoverable I would like to get Ubuntu installed and working once again.

Comment: I’d be inclined to boot the machine into a live environment (e.g. the Ubuntu installation media) and use smartctl to query the drive health. The message you have reported is not necessarily the cause of the failure to boot. The real cause may be the next step in the boot process.